# Can the Blade Ward cantrip be cast on other people?

Tags: dnd-5e, targeting, cantrips

Can the *blade ward* cantrip be cast on other people?

On the page I read it on, it said *blade ward* had a range of 5 feet, but in the description, it used terms that made it seem like it could only be used on your self. I just want a little clarification.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the rules? Your questions make it sound like you are googling for all your information, or at least a portion of it.

Comment: ^ Yep, Blade Ward is listed clearly with a range of "self", not "5 feet". Make sure to use official sources when checking rules.

Comment: @SeriousBri What's wrong with googling exactly? I've googled for "blade ward" and the first link gave me "Range: self".

Comment: @encryptor it leads people here to ask pretty basic questions which would be less likely if they had the actual material. I was trying to be helpful. I Google stuff all the time, but know how to tell the real results from all the homebrew for example.

Comment: My friend is currently borrowing my phb and I have a different source that I used, that’s my bad

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### No, *blade ward* can only target the caster

The range of [*blade ward*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/blade-ward) is "self", and the description says it affects only you:

> Until the end of your next turn, you have resistance against bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing damage dealt by weapon attacks.

See the Player's Handbook, page 218.

Comment: Or a paladin’s found steed.